# Can't iterate a JSON array

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use different way of putting data in to SQL using "SqlBulkCopy", and I am getting some error.

Bottom is what currently working without issue for now.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ILogger logger = Bootstrap.Logger("");                     
    string paramValue = SayHello(logger);

    string connString = @"Data Source=net;USER id=admin;Password=ess;Initial Catalog=fin";

    string sprocname = "InsertPerfCounterData3";
    string paramName = "@json";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocname, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramName, paramValue));

            cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
```

Currently, paramValue has this output:

```
"[{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756289-919567--accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756290-919568--accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}]"
```

I am trying to use bottom code, instead:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("RECORDNO", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("BATCH_DATE", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var r in paramValue.Data)
    table.Rows.Add(r.RECORDNO, r.BATCH_DATE);

const string connString1 = @"Data Source=net;USER id=admin;Password=ess;Initial Catalog=fin";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "PerfCounter3";
    conn.Open();
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

This is area where I am getting error, and I am not sure how to modify:

[image]

**Update (5/10/2022):**

I need some help regards to how to insert data properly as I am getting an error like shown below:

I did not include all other Class codes.

I need some help to iterate each line to database.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ILogger logger = Bootstrap.Logger("");                     
    string paramValue = SayHello(logger);

    const string connString = @"Data Source=net;USER id=admin;Password=ess;Initial Catalog=fin";

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wossit[]>(paramValue);

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("RECORDNO", typeof(Char));
    table.Columns.Add("BATCH_DATE", typeof(DateTime));

    foreach (var record in data)
        table.Rows.Add($"{record.Detail.RecordNumber}, {record.Detail.BatchDate}");

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        bulk.DestinationTableName = "PerfCounter4";
        conn.Open();
        bulk.WriteToServer(table);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
HResult=0x80070057
Message=String must be exactly one character long.Couldn't store 
<264378-1756289-919567--accrual, 2/1/2022 12:00:00 AM> in RECORDNO 
Column. Expected type is Char.
Source=System.Data.Common
StackTrace:
at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object value)
at System.Data.DataTable.NewRecordFromArray(Object[] value)
at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
at Sage0413.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\..\Main.cs:line 65

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

[External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
FormatException: String must be exactly one character long.
```

Comment: Why do you think that `paramValue` should have a `Data` property? The only place I see it declared in your code, it is type `string`. Where exactly are you expecting the data to come from? Is that supposed to be JSON? If so then you need to parse it into some object from which you can then read the data. It's not coming straight out of a `string`.

Comment: Your question title is kinda missleading, you are not having issues with the bulk copy code because you are having the error before the bulk copy code gets executed.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy has nothing to do with JSON parsing. Post only the relevant code and the actual error. In fact, where's the JSON parsing code?

Comment: Are you getting an error saying that `String` has no `Data` property? It doesn't and neither does your JSON string. Even if you could somehow treat a JSON string as an object or array of objects without parsing, that string has no `Data` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a JSON parse step. You can't magically get from a string to data - you need to *interpret* the data; perhaps something like:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

string json = "[{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756289-919567--accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756290-919568--accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}]";

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wossit[]>(json);
foreach (var record in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{record.Detail.RecordNumber}, {record.Detail.BatchDate}");
}


class Wossit
{
    [JsonProperty("GLDETAIL")]
    public Somet Detail { get; set; }
}
class Somet
{
    [JsonProperty("RECORDNO")]
    public string RecordNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("BATCH_DATE")]
    public DateTime BatchDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And then of course `Object.CreateReader` to avoid creating a DataTable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos which API is that? is that `ObjectReader.Create` from FastMember ? if so: I won't disagree (funnily enough), but: baby steps :)

Comment: Duuh, need another coffee. BTW what are you doing late September? Fancy a trip to Athens for https://voxxeddays.com/athens/ ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos very tempting (my next door neighbours are Greek expats - we do food swaps a lot, and: noms), but travel is still a major PITA at the moment :(

Comment: @MarcGravell I updated the content with current code that I am getting an error. Please see where it has "Update (5/10/2022):"

Comment: @Java when you add the column to the DataTable, use `string`, not `char`

Answer (score 2):

Your exception shows you what is happening. You are trying to insert a `VARCHAR` into a `CHAR` field in your database (the one for RECORDNO that you initially has as an `INT`).

A `CHAR` is one single character, your RECORDNO is a string of variable characters -- `VARCHAR`, which most closely matches a c# `string`.

Try changing `table.Columns.Add("RECORDNO", typeof(Char));` to `table.Columns.Add("RECORDNO", typeof(String));` to see if it fixes your issue.

**EDIT:**

It seems you are also passing in a single string into the table row here:

`table.Rows.Add($"{record.Detail.RecordNumber}, {record.Detail.BatchDate}");`

Which may not be what you wanted.

It may help to add the data to the table using the [`Add(Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.add?view=net-6.0#system-data-datarowcollection-add(system-object())) method. I think you are currently passing in a character array to that method -- `$"{record.Detail.RecordNumber}, {record.Detail.BatchDate}"` may be interpreted  as a character array and accepted as a parameter for the add method without issue.

Perhaps changing

`table.Rows.Add($"{record.Detail.RecordNumber}, {record.Detail.BatchDate}");`

to

`table.Rows.Add(new object[]{record.Detail.RecordNumber, record.Detail.BatchDate});`

will solve your issue.

Comment: It still shows the same error after I changed from Char to String

Comment: Is your database table also defined with RECORDNO as a char? That exception 'String must be exactly one character long...' is specifically saying there is an issue with the data being inserted in that column. It may be that the data is the wrong format, or the table was expecting the wrong data type. If you could provide more of the stack trace it may give insight as to what is actually causing the error.

Comment: I updated the content with Stacktrace. Error occurred before hitting the database I think.

Comment: Added an edit to my post, you should still make sure you change your column type to string as well. Your stack trace is showing it as Char still, which won't be able to store a string in it (depending on the length of the string).

Comment: Your recommendation to change to "new object[]" solved the issue. Thanks!